# Android Gradle execution failed on data binding

Tags: android, gradle, javac, android-databinding

I am getting gradle build error ; execution failed for task ':app:compileDevelopmentDebugJavaWithJavac' , error: cannot find symbol.. It's really headache now. Here is the gradle logs ;

> symbol:   variable activity_live_chat_view
>   location: class layout
>   D:\New\android-app\app\build\generated\source\apt\development\debug\android\databinding\DataBinderMapper.java:109: error: cannot find symbol
>                       return abc.abc.R.layout.activity_live_chat_view;
>     symbol:   variable activity_live_chat_view
>     location: class layout
>   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>   36 errors
>   FAILED

Codes that error refers:

```
 @Override
public void onBind(ChatMessage message) {
    super.onBind(message);
    mBinding.chatUserNameTv.setText(message.getUserName());
    mBinding.chatMediaGifIv.setFreezesAnimation(true);
    mBinding.chatMediaGifIv.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        mBinding.chatMediaGifIv.setFreezesAnimation(false);
    });
}
```

when I ctrl+click the item, it is linked to xml also, there is no problem on it.
I dont know what is wrong, why this happend? pls advise on this, Regards

EDIT Layout file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/chat_view_parent_padding">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chat_avatar_iv"
        style="@style/ChatStyleAvatar"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        style="@style/ChatStyleCardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp5"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/chat_card_min_height">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp5"
                android:padding="@dimen/dp5">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/chat_user_name_tv"
                    style="@style/ChatStyleText.UserName"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text="user name" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/chat_message_tv"
                    style="@style/ChatStyleText.Message"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/chat_user_name_tv"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp10"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chat_block_ib"
                    android:text="Gif message" />

                <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
                    android:id="@+id/chat_media_gif_iv"
                    style="@style/ChatStyleMediaGif"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/chat_message_tv"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp5"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp5"
                    android:src="@drawable/giphy" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/chat_block_ib"
                    style="@style/ChatStyleIconButton"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_block" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing build folder and running again?

Comment: @RobertK. yes..

Comment: If I had to guess, it may be related to your use of apt -- it looks like you're using it based on the error. `apt` isn't supported anymore, so try removing it and just using the `annotationProcessor` syntax in your gradle file instead. It could also be something to do with a module dependency that needs to be rebuilt.